# Python variable name with two dots : on the name

Tags: python, apache-spark

I've been reading this tutorial about Spark and I've found this code snippet

```
spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("Another_app.com").getOrCreate()
```

i don´t understand why the variable name has two dots on it. Is this some kind of typing on Python I've never worked before?

Comment: That's not part of the name, it's a type hint after the name. We usually put a space after the `:` to separate them.

Comment: Also note that "two dots" generally means `..` and not the colon character `:`